# JerseyTest doesn't recognize @WebFilter

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, junit4, jersey-2.0

I try to create a JerseyTest on a Jersey REST Servlet with jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2.

The test requests correct content from the servlet in grizzly.

But when starting up the servlet productive there is an HTTPBasicAuth.
The Auth is done with a @WebFilter("/*") org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter.

During JerseyTest there is no Auth requested. 
So my conclusion is that the @WebFilter annotation is not recognized.
Does JerseyTest only test resources in the Application?
How to get the WebFilters recognized?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer myself ;-)

It's a JerseyTest Framework and no "FullAppWithJerseyTest" Framework.

I've now implemented something like ServletJerseyTest extending JerseyTest.
It uses the org.glassfish.jersey.test.external.ExternalTestContainerFactory.class and setUp() contains starting up a servlet container and installing the latest built WAR.

The test runs against this container. In tearDown() the container is stopped and installed WAR becomes deleted.

Embedded Tomcat has API to look by itself for a free TCP port and TestProperties.CONTAINER_PORT is set to choosen port.

Now the tests run as expected...

Comment: If you know a better more generic solution without assumptions about the build system to get to know the WAR which should be tested against... Your answers will be welcome!